# Alert Radio Input in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to write a form when I ask the user to write if they like to eat or not. However, no matter what they answer, the answer comes out "yes". What is the problem with this code?

```
    <form>
    Do you like food?<br>

    <input type="radio" id="validate" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="validate" value="no">No<br>

    <br><br>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="eatFood()">
</form>
<script>
function eatFood() {
    var y = document.getElementById("validate").value;
    alert(y);


}
</script>
```

Comment: Id must be unique, everytime you are getting the first element with id.

Comment: I edited my answer, the first way is the better, please let me know if you are having any problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the most simple way to get a radio input value using JavaScript:

```
function eatFood() {
    var choice = document.querySelector('input[name = validate]:checked').value;
    alert(choice);
}
```

Working demo : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/ppQzeL

---

Here is the **a second** way :

```
function eatFood() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName('validate');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
  {
   if (radios[i].checked)
   {
     alert(radios[i].value);
     break;
   }
  }
}
```

Second way working demo : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/XVyrJB

---

Here is **third way**, if you only have two radios input :

```
function eatFood() {
  if (document.getElementById('yes').checked) {
    result = document.getElementById('yes').value;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('no').checked) {
    result = document.getElementById('no').value;
  }
  alert(result);
}
```

Third way working demo : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/KZrPVy

Answer (score 1):

You missed the name attribute, this is necessary to group radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="validate" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="validate" value="no">No<br>
```

The id must be unique, fixing the JavaScript function with this, the result would be the next (as André's answer):

```
function eatFood() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('validate');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
  {
     if (radios[i].checked)
     {
       alert(radios[i].value);
       break;
     }
  }
}
```